# Homotopy equivalence between $\mathbb R^3\setminus\text{$x$-axis}$ and $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb R^3\setminus \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid y=z=0\}$. Show that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried already? If you don't show effort posts often get downvoted.

Comment: I know, how to find mapping from $R^2\(0,0)$ to $S^1$, but I don't know how to show that X is homotopy equivalence to $R^2\(0,)$. Should I try with fundamental group ?

Comment: Do you know how to show that for any topological space $Z$, the space $Z\times \mathbb{R}$ is homotopy equivalent to $Z$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $X$ is just $\mathbb R^3$ minus the $x$-axis. Now try to show that $X\to \mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z)$ is a homotopy equivalence. Afterwards use your knowledge about $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and $S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

For any topological space $Z$, there is a deformation retract from $Z\times \mathbb{R}$ onto the subspace $A=Z\times \{0\}$ and so $Z\times\mathbb{R}$ is homotopy equivalent to $Z\cong Z\times\{0\}$. (You should prove this proposition if you haven't already)

Use this, together with the fact that $S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, that homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation for topological spaces and $X\cong Y\times\mathbb{R}$.